# Javascript single single quotation

Tags: javascript, html, tags

In this code, when the `basis` variable has a single quotation, something like `"Father's Day"` then I am getting a problem because the tag is being closed at the point where single quotation is being encountered.

```
'success' : function(data) {
    div.innerHTML = '<a href=\'javascript:blockConcept("'+tld+'","'+basis+'","'+admin_id+'","'+url+'")\' class="block">Block concept for '+ tld+'</a>'
}
```

Comment: What's your *question*?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I escape strings?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the single quotes in `basis` (and the others) using `replace`:

```
... + basis.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + ...
```

...but that leaves you open to other issues (for instance, line breaks). You might consider outputting the `tld`, `basis`, and such as attributes on the element, and then calling `blockConcept` passing in `this` so that it can retrieve the information from the element. Or passing a single argument that you encode with `JSON.stringify` (you may need a shim, not all browsers have it natively yet).